# BroadcastReceiver - cannot find registerReceiver inside SystemSensorManager

Tags: android-source, android-build, android-framework

I want to use BroadcastReceiver inside SystemSensorManager class (android.hardware). I managed to define an object of type BroadcastReceiver but when I tried to register this receiver using :

```
registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)
```

This method cannot be found and the source code doesnt compile.

I tried the to do similar thing in the Activity class and it succeeded. whats wrong with the SystemSensorManager  class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) is defined on [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and its descendants. **SystemSensorManager** receives **context** in constructor, but does not remember it. You should find a relevant `Context` for your change.